# Preventing duplicates with addError

Tags: apex, trigger, adderror

So basically was trying to prevent duplicates in my Lead Trigger by checking the lead's email and crossing it with the Contact object in order to verify that no contact with the same email exists.

The problem is that when I tried using the `addError` in the `before insert` event, I found that all the leads in the trigger got rolled back instead of just the one that was duplicated.

This is the code I used in the trigger:

```
public static void addErrorIfContactExists(List<Lead> newLeadList) {
        Map<String, Lead> leadsByPrimaryEmail = new Map<String, Lead>();
        for(Lead lead : newLeadList) {
            leadsByPrimaryEmail.put(lead.Email, lead);
        }

        for(Contact con : [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN: leadsByPrimaryEmail.keySet()]) {
            if(leadsByPrimaryEmail.containsKey(con.Email)) {
                leadsByPrimaryEmail.get(con.Email).addError('A contact with this email already exists');
            }
        }
    }
```

And when running the following in the test, I found both were rolled back:

```
Lead l1 = new Lead(Company = 'Unknown', LastName = 'Error Record', Email = 'aaa@bbb.ccc'); // There is a contact with this email in DB.
Lead l2 = new Lead(Company = 'Unknown', LastName = 'Correct Record');

insert new List<Lead> {l1, l2};
```

So, my question is... what is the best way to do this which I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calling context has to allow partial success. This approach will fail every record:

```
 insert recordsWithDuplicates;
```

This record will allow successful records to save:

```
Database.insert(recordsWithDuplicates, /*allOrNone*/ false);
```

Comment: But the issue is I was trying to add the error in the before insert, so I ain't really doing an insert myself, right?

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Within the trigger, you have no control over how this validation will behave. *The calling context controls partial success behavior.*

Comment: So, given this scenario, I guess the best approach isn't using a trigger... Is there some other tool in Salesforce to help me achieve exactly this?

Comment: In your unit test, you do control the calling context... Change `insert new List<Lead>{...}` to `Database.insert(new List<Lead>{...}, false)`.

Comment: Ok, that just helped me visualize your actual answer haha. Thanks! :)